# Excel Data Validation not giving error message

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I am trying to get a simple data validation in a cell with VBA. For some reason, when I type something that is not in the selected list (Y or N), I dont receive the error message and Excel allows me to put whatever I want in the cell.

Any help appreciated!

```
Sub Data_Validation_Critical()

    'Critical:
    Range("B4").Select
        With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=DVEmergentCritical"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = "ERROR: Invalid Selection"
        .InputMessage = "Y or N"
        .ErrorMessage = _
        "You have entered and invalid seleciton. Please select Y or N."
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This code works as expected for me.

Comment: It should be noted that you're not fully qualifying your range.  As such this will only apply it to the Active Sheet of the Active Workbook.  Perhaps that's the issue?

Comment: @tigeravatar is definately right. You should fully qualify your code to make sure that the validation check is made to the correct `Range("B4")` on the sheet you want (and not a randomly selected / active sheet). Other than that the code works for me too. But if you want to accept `Y` and `N` only then you might as well change your code to `.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="Y,N"`

Comment: Hi tigeravatar and Ralph! Thanks for your help. I went ahead and selected a worksheet above the code I already wrote. I subbed in Ralph's suggestion as well. It does work, but when I copy the cell and paste it into the next row, the problem starts up again. I can type whatever I want in and it doesnt give the error. Any ideas?

Comment: The solution isn't to `Select` a worksheet and keep implicitly working against `ActiveSheet`......

Answer (score 0):

Another way to validate data could be:

```
If Range("B4").Value = "Y" Then
   DoSomeStuff
ElseIf Range("B4").Value = "N" Then
   DoSomeStuff
Else
   DoNothing or Msgbox Error.
End If
```